Exporting both .blend and .fbx file from Blender to Unity creates unexpected results
I created a basic rigged character to act as a placeholder character for a game. The character has a short walking animation that was made by parenting basic objects in my scene to the bones of the armature, and keying the movement of the bones in pose mode. The bones don't have any special properties other than having IK on the arm and leg bones.
The animation appears to work fine in blender, but when exporting to unity, the only motion applied when playing the animation is to the bone in the torso, where it moves up and down a bit. All motion assigned to other bones is completely ignored, and the model just rigidly moves with the torso bone.
What I have tried so far:
1: Baking animation into an action in the NLA editor rather than using keys (which I have never used before, and am unsure how it works)
2: Exporting in different formats than .blend, since I can control export settings easier when exporting as a .fbx.
3: Adjusting the axes in the export settings to make the up axis correspond to the one in unity
4: Parenting all other bones to the torso bone (messes with IK though)
These are the export settings I used when exporting as a .fbx:


And this is the model + armature. It looks the same in Unity, with the exception of the animation issue.

This feels like a scenario where enabling or disabling an export setting would fix my issue, but I cannot seem to find a solution, so I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable can figure this out.
Here's the file:


All these relationship lines pointing to different places aren't reassuring. Are all your bones within the same armature object? To they have one unique bone at the top of the hierarchy (usually named "root" bone at the ground center of the character, as it's useful for global placement, offset and other things). When you manually bake, have you enabled visual keying and constraint clearing? That's the important part of baking and I don't think it is done in the FBX exporter's animation baking process.

If you are unsure of these, please consider to share your file.

Sorry, for taking long to respond @Lauloque. To your first question, yes, all ten of my bones are shown as being within the same armature object in the hierarchy. As for the root bone, I haven't made many rigged models so I typically just parent one bone to all other bones with keep offset, but this breaks the IK on the arms and legs, so I haven't added a root bone. Is this essential for rigged models, or just convenient? I also enabled visual keying and cleared object constraints, but it doesn't seem to have much of an effect. I'll share my file if you think that you can help.

If your bones' hierarchy starts from one unique bone, at least you avoid lots of technical issues like compatibility. Having a dedicated "root" bone adds lots of conveniences that can become major depending on the rig. Seeing the file directly would be nice then.

Sorry if there's a delay in sharing the file, blend exchange is throwing an internal error every time I try and upload my 0.3MB file despite me trying two different devices with a valid internet connection.

Don't worry about the delay, we're all here on whatever free time we have and from all around the world, there's no time expectation. I had the same error on my side, there seemed to be an issue with BE. I reported it and it's already fixed, you can try again.

Thanks, it works fine now, and I embedded the file in my post

I tried baking the animation as I mentioned and then exporting with options as I would do all the time, and importing that back to Blender I notice the armature and its animation have no problem getting exported. However it's the mesh objects that ended up not following the bones at all. Which I believe is because of how you made the bone-mesh relationship; you parented your mesh objects to the bones:

The thing is, when it comes to exporting and importing, the only real trustworthy method you can be sure to be supported by any format and software that supports bone animation is using weights (vertex groups).
So first we'll need to change the skinning method to vertex groups and then export again.
Using Vertex groups

In Object mode, select all your mesh objects, then ⇧ Shift select your armature
Open the Set Parent To menu with ⎈ CtrlP and chose Armature Deform With Empty Groups

For each mesh object:

Go in Edit mode
Select all the mesh
Select the vertex group of the bone you want to affect that mesh and press Assign:




Baking before exporting
When you want to export, first make sure to save your file as a copy. Baking will be a destructive operation you only need for the exported data, you don't want to keep it in your work file.
When you are ready, select your armature object, ↹ Tab to Pose mode, select all your bones and hit F3 to search and run the Bake Action operator.
The important options are the start/end frames, visual keying to make keyframes that store the coordinates of your bones with their constraints (otherwise they would store the transform relative to the constraints), and enable clear constraint to remove the IK constraint that become redundant and could cause issues at export.
Since you already use actions in your file, you don't want to enable overwriting actions.

Export options
In object mode, select your mesh objects and the armature, and go to File > Export > FBX.


Include

Enable Limit to Selected Objects


Transform

Default options should be good


Armature

Enable Only Deform Bones. I don't think you have non-deform bones in your rig, but it could happen in the future and you don't need them when exporting, it's a waste of data and gives confusing skeletons to deal with in your game engine.
Disable Add Leaf Bones, useless in a game engine (and arguably anywhere, it's just a trick to make bone-based systems look the same way when exported in a joint-based system. Purely visual not functional)


Animation

Enable Key All Bones
Disable NLA Strips and All Actions, since here we really want to export only the action we just baked.



Export, and reopen your file to revert the baking. The resulting FBX should be good to go:


Thank you! Assigning vertex groups to bones rather than parenting objects worked perfectly. Luckily unity lets you import .blend files directly, so it appears functional there without having to toggle the export settings you suggested for .fbx files.
